# modifying footer in Wordpress X

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, footer

I've been looking around for the solution to this problem I've been having, but everything seems to be a little outdated/not solving the issue.

I'm currently editing a Wordpress website using X theme (Icon site template). I've been trying to figure out how to change the background color of the header and the footer of my site. I've tried modifying the CSS of them with no avail. All I'm trying to accomplish is having a black footer background with white social icons.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, please let me know!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - I'll point you to the direction of the Wordpress StackExchange site :) - The question seems better suited for that (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

inspect from chrome developer tools and and see the regarding tag. You can test it like this :

```
header, footer {
    background-color: black !important;
}
```

Keep in mind that !important is not good for production.